# Get Redshift cluster status in outputs of cloudformation

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a redshift cluster using CF and then I need to output the cluster status (basically if its available or not). There are ways to output the endpoints and port but I could not find any possible way of outputting the status.

How can I get that, or it is not possible ?

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to output the status?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. According to [AWS::Redshift::Cluster - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html), the only available outputs are `Endpoint.Address` and `Endpoint.Port`.

Status is not something that you'd normally want to output from CloudFormation because the value changes.

If you *really* want to wait until the cluster is available, you could create a `WaitCondition` and then have something monitor the status and the signal for the Wait Condition to continue. This would probably need to be an Amazon EC2 instance with some User Data. Linux instances are charged per-second, so this would be quite feasible.

Comment: I actually want to track the status and when the cluster goes down, I need to restore the cluster using the snapshot. But not sure how to go about this change through code.

Comment: The probability of needing to automate such a restoration is very low. Drive failures are handled due to backups on other nodes. An AZ failure is extremely rare. Some resources to consult: [Amazon Redshift FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/faqs/), [Building Multi-AZ or Multi-Region Amazon Redshift Clusters | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-multi-az-or-multi-region-amazon-redshift-clusters/), [Amazon Redshift and Designing for Resilience - All Things Distributed](https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2013/02/amazon-redshift-resilience.html).

Comment: You could use [Amazon Redshift Metrics and Dimensions - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rs-metricscollected.html) to trigger an AWS Lambda function when `HealthStatus` changes. The Lambda function could then perform actions.

Comment: Yeah will try this. Thanks.